# Issue with using Hibernate in Jersey service

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jersey

I have tried so many option in resolving the issue and fed up.  Finally came here for suggestions.  I am a beginner in Hibernate and Jersey.  I am trying to fetch data from a Jersey GET service using Hibernate with Maven, but I got the following exception

```
 Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
 Dec 14, 2014 12:59:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/trailassignment] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException:          java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:936)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:781)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3762)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3716)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
at devfactor.trailassignment.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:21)
at devfactor.trailassignment.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:11)
at devfactor.trailassignment.ProductService.listProducts(ProductService.java:13)
at devfactor.trailassignment.MyResource.getTrackInJSON(MyResource.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:172)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:384)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:342)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
```

I am using tomcat server to host

Following is the web.xml

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>devfactor.trailassignment</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webresources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Following are in pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>devfactor</groupId>
<artifactId>trailassignment</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>trailassignment Jersey Webapp</name>
<build>
    <finalName>trailassignment</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Jersey dependencies <dependency> <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId> <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId> 
        <version>2.0.1</version> <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.14</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>asm</groupId>
                <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>asm</groupId>
                <artifactId>asm-attrs</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.CR2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Service code is as follows (bare with bad design)

```
  @GET 
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getTrackInJSON() {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    Query q = session.createQuery("From Product");

    List<Product> resultList = q.list();
    session.close();
    HibernateUtil.shutdown();
    return resultList .get(0).getDescription();

}
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
 public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
 //         Configuration  configuration = new Configuration().configure("../resources/com/gteam/salesorder/config/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        Configuration  configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                configuration.getProperties()).build();
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void shutdown() {
    // Close caches and connection pools
    getSessionFactory().close();
}

 }
```

Please help me out in resolving in issue?

Thanks in advance.